# HTTPS TLS 1.2 using wildfly

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly

I am trying to setup wildly to use HTTPS with tls 1.2 using wildlfy. Upon deploy i get this handshake error:

2020-12-10 11:44:33,416 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) default task-1, fatal error: 40: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
2020-12-10 11:44:33,416 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported

2020-12-10 11:44:33,417 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) %% Invalidated:  [Session-3, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]

2020-12-10 11:44:33,419 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) default task-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure

2020-12-10 11:44:33,420 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) default task-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

2020-12-10 11:44:33,421 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-14) default I/O-14, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported

2020-12-10 11:44:33,422 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-14) default I/O-14, called closeInbound()

2020-12-10 11:44:33,422 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-14) default I/O-14, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?

2020-12-10 11:44:33,423 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-14) default I/O-14, called closeOutbound()

2020-12-10 11:44:33,423 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-14) default I/O-14, closeOutboundInternal()

2020-12-10 11:44:34,424 INFO  [stdout] (default I/O-7) Using SSLEngineImpl.

In the config i have

```
<server name="default-server">
  <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="974247881" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
  <https-listener enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2" max-parameters="50000" max-post-size="0" name="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" socket-binding="https"/>
  <host alias="localhost" name="default-host">
    <location handler="welcome-content" name="/"/>
    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
  </host>
</server>

What does this handshake error mean? what is wrong with the configuration?
```

Comment: **IT TELLS YOU:** `Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported` . A client is trying to connect with TLS v1 (meaning v1.0) and you configured to prohibit 1.0. If you want to accept this client, allow 1.0. If you don't want to allow 1.0, don't use this client.

Comment: How do you check what TLS is enabled/disabled on a machine? How do you know which is the default one?

Comment: TLS versions are not per machine, they are per server program. For your Wildfly it's right there in the config you posted: `enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"`. If you didn't have that config, I don't know what Wildfly's default is, but at a guess it might be the JVM's default, which is usually all supported versions other than SSLv3 because that's broken.